# Get all ids from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got my collection items like this :

```
hotels = Hotel.where('selection = ?', 1).limit(4)
```

How can I get all ids of this items without a loop? Can i use something like :

```
hotels.ids ?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What about trying `hotels.map(&:id)` or `hotels.map{|h| h.id }`?

They both mean the same thing to Ruby, the first one is nicer to accustomed ruby-ists usually, whilst the second one is easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: It should be `hotels.map(&:id)`. Otherwise, I agree with the answer

Comment: `hotels.map(&:id)` would be nicer. edit: outraced by @DanneManne :-)

Comment: @DanneManne Good catch for the typo: bites me every time :/

Answer (score 27):

If you only need an array with all the ids you should use **[pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)** as it makes the right query and you don't have to use any ruby. Besides it won't have to instantiate a Hotel object for each record returned from the DB. (way faster).

```ruby
Hotel.where(selection: 1).pluck(:id)
# SELECT hotels.id FROM hotels WHERE hotels.selection = 1
# => [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Rails > 4, you can use the `ids` method:

```
Person.ids  # SELECT people.id from people
```

More info: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ids

Comment: Rails 5 return `Array < Object` class

Answer (score 9):

You can also pull just the id's.

```
hotels.select(:id).where(selection: 1)
```

Comment: Most objective, easy and fast solution. It's seems so obvious, but people insist using enumerable methods for **everything**.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6+ has added something called `extract_associated` [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/extract_associated) | [blog](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/08/15/rails-6-extract-associated/)

Where the association (`has_many`) of a collection/list can be queried.

Example, a Company has many hotels and each hotel `has_many` managers, to get all the hotel managers associated user id:

```
hotels = Company.hotels.active
hotels.extract_associated(:mangers).flatten.pluck(:user_id)
```